# How to set value to input field in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase

How to set the value to the input field in react. Data is fetching from firebase.
I was trying to fetch data from the firebase and then data is populated to the input field. But data is sometimes set to input field sometimes not.

Comment: Can you please provide some code?

Answer (score 1):

You have to fill your data into a local state using useState. Here is the general idea. Can't go into more details without  code example from your side.

For example:

```
const [value, setValue] = useState('')
```

Then in your useEffect fetching the data:

```
useEffect(() => {
   const data = fetch('gettingdata') // replace by the way you get your data
   setValue(data)
 }, []}
```

Then in your input:

```
<input value={value} onChange={manageYourValueChange} />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the useRef hook to avoid unnecessary rerender:

```
import {useRef, userEffect} from 'react'

const Test:React.FC = () => {
   const inputRef = useRef(null)

   userEffect(() => {
      const resp = yourAsyncGetData()
      inputRef.current.value = (resp)
   }, [])

   return <input ref={inputRef} />
}

export default Test
```